# Chart range based on the value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a line chart that selects a range of data based on the value in a cell. For instance, in cell C1 I write A1:B4, this means the chart is a display of the data in cells A1 to B4. If I simply change the value in cell C1 to A1:B9, I want the chart to display the data of this range - you get the point. This shouldn't be too hard, but i'm not getting it right (and for some reason the web is full of the same examples that do not apply for my)

I've tried using a `Named Range` function. I still think this is the way to go, but I need some help.

Comment: Surely you must have tried one of those examples and something went wrong. If you show what you have tried and what exactly the problem was, it will be easier for others to help you.

Comment: I have, this one for example:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHfWRb2yUrM, but not useful. I'm guessing this should be a quick fix for someone how knows.

Comment: What does it mean "want the chart to display the data of this range"? A chart always needs **two** ranges one for the categories (or x-values) and one for the category values (or y-values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `VBA` needed for this.

Let's start having the following worksheet named `Sheet1`:

[image]

Now we need three named ranges. One for the whole range which we get indirect form `C1`, one for the categories which is the left column of the whole range and one for the values which is the right column of the whole range.

So in name manager we create following named ranges:

[image]

Note all named ranges are in scope of the sheet `Sheet1` and **not** in workbook scope. So while creating the named ranges, always choose scope `Sheet1` instead of `Workbook`

Name `myRange` refers to `=INDIRECT(Sheet1!$C$1)`. So it gets it's range from that cell value.

Name `myCategories` refers to `=INDEX(Sheet1!myRange,,1)`. That gets all rows (since no special row is given) from column `1` of `myRange`.

Name `myValues` refers to `=INDEX(Sheet1!myRange,,2)`. That gets all rows (since no special row is given) from column `2` of `myRange`.

Now we can insert a chart (a pie chart for example).

Then we right-click the chart, and then choose `Select Data`.

First we delete all present series on left side below Legend Entries (Series), if any. Then we add a new series. In Series values: we put the formula `=Sheet1!myValues`, `OK`.

On right side below Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels we click `Edit` and put in the formula `=Sheet1!myCategories`, `OK`.

Then `OK` for the whole select-data-dialog.

Now if we change the cell value of `C1` into something what `INDIRECT` can interpret as a cell range, then the chart will change too.

---

To give a `VBA` solution also:

Let's have the same sheet as above. Data in `A1:B8` and range address in `C1`.

Now create the wanted chart. It must be the one and only chart object in that sheet.

Now put the following code in sheet module of `Sheet1` (right click on the sheet tab and click `View Code`):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim oChartObject As ChartObject
 Dim oChart As Chart
 If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 3 Then
  On Error Resume Next
  Set oChartObject = Me.ChartObjects(1)
  Set oChart = oChartObject.Chart
  oChart.SetSourceData Source:=Me.Range(Target.Value)
  On Error GoTo 0
 End If
End Sub
```

This code leads to changing of source data of the chart if the value of `C1` (row 1, column 3) changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and great explanation @Axel Richter!

Comment: @Axel Richter in the VBA solution, how do I set the value if the target value is in another sheet (Data) and the chart is in another (Dashboard)?
i tried using Worksheets("Dashboard").ChartObjects("Sales") and Source:=WorkSheets("Data").Range(Target .Value) and was giving me debug errors

Comment: @rellik: That is a different requirement than in this question. It is worth a new question. One question here should not hold answers to all related questions too.

Comment: @Axel Richter of course, I have a similar question asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159008/excel-activechart-setsourcedata-source-runtime-error-445-object-doesnt-s but the solution was nowhere near clean as this that's why i asked.here.

Comment: @AxelRichter new question asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588100/excel-chart-range-based-on-the-value-in-a-cell-in-another-sheet